# MySQL: Use CONCAT() as a colum name in WHERE statement of a sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery, concatenation

This is my first question on stackoverflow, but I have been reading it for years so far. So please be forgiving if my question is not appropriate. I have been searching the web for hours and did not find anything.

I am currently optimizing queries of a system working on a MySQL database. One table is holding sums of another table to speed up the frontend showing these sums. The query I ended up is replacing multiple other queries and loops in the code... if it would be working :)

This is the one not working as expected:

```
SELECT 
v.*, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.display_item_id)
  FROM search_index_item i
  WHERE i.path LIKE '238/2/257/%'
  AND i.scope_id = v.scope_id
  AND CONCAT('i.attribute_', v.attribute_id) LIKE CONCAT('%|', v.attribute_value_id, '|%')
) 
AS item_count
FROM search_index_category_attribute_value v
WHERE v.category_id = 257
```

The query is working so far, but the calculated "item_count" is always 0. The reason why its 0 is the statement "CONCAT('i.attribute_', v.attribute_id)" which seems not to be handled as a field name. When I replace this statement with the good column name, it returns a value:

```
SELECT 
v.*, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.display_item_id)
  FROM search_index_item i
  WHERE i.path LIKE '238/2/257/%'
  AND i.scope_id = v.scope_id
  AND i.attribute_7 LIKE CONCAT('%|', v.attribute_value_id, '|%')
) 
AS item_count
FROM search_index_category_attribute_value v
WHERE v.category_id = 257
```

This now works, but of course only for a single attribute_id (7). As the attribute ID is stored in another table and then saved as single column in a non-normalized table for performance purposes, I need to create the column name dynamically. Of course I can do it in the code, but this is rather slow and unwanted.

Do you guys have an idea of how to force MySQL to handle "CONCAT('i.attribute_', v.attribute_id)" as a field instead of a string?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: While it's always great to see what you've done, and that you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself, it's also useful to provide proper DDLs (and/or and sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET so that we can better understand what it is you're actually trying to do. (Tiny bit disappointed that such a long time follower hadn't grasped that already)

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is flawed.
If you cannot normalize data, then try to rewrite this clause:

```
AND CONCAT('i.attribute_', v.attribute_id) LIKE CONCAT('%|', v.attribute_value_id, '|%')
```

into this monster:

```
AND CASE v.attribute_id 
       WHEN 1 THEN i.attribute_1
       WHEN 2 THEN i.attribute_2
       WHEN 3 THEN i.attribute_3
       WHEN 4 THEN i.attribute_4
       .......
       .......
       .......
       WHEN 998 THEN i.attribute_998 
       WHEN 999 THEN i.attribute_999  
       WHEN 1000 THEN i.attribute_1000
   END
 LIKE CONCAT('%|', v.attribute_value_id, '|%')
```

This probably will work, however it wont be fast - this query must always do a full table scan, it cannot use any index.